Project is not running while debugging .NET project in Fleet
I am not able to debug project since project is not running in .NET.
I have crated a .NET web api project in 8. I have tried all links from launchSettings.json with /swagger at the end.
Steps I have done to Run

CTRL + R
CTRL + Enter (Debug)

I am getting below logs but not any swagger like generally you get while running project.
     3>Done Building Project "D:\PracticeC#\fleet\ConfigTest.Service\ConfigTest.Service.csproj" (default targets). 2>GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute: Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files. CoreGenerateAssemblyInfo: Skipping target "CoreGenerateAssemblyInfo" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files. _DiscoverMvcApplicationParts: Skipping target "_DiscoverMvcApplicationParts" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files. _GenerateSourceLinkFile: Source Link is empty, file 'obj\Debug\net8.0\ConfigTest.API.sourcelink.json' does not exist. CoreCompile: Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files. _CreateAppHost: Skipping target "_CreateAppHost" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files. _GenerateScopedCssFiles: Skipping target "_GenerateScopedCssFiles" because it has no outputs. _GenerateScopedCssFiles: Skipping target "_GenerateScopedCssFiles" because it has no outputs. _BuildCopyStaticWebAssetsPreserveNewest: Skipping target "_BuildCopyStaticWebAssetsPreserveNewest" because it has no outputs. _CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory: Skipping target "_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files. GenerateBuildDependencyFile: Skipping target "GenerateBuildDependencyFile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files. GenerateBuildRuntimeConfigurationFiles:
Debug Screen
